# Querying XML data fails for element with a default namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

Why am I getting a blank result for the second `SELECT` query and the first query returns the result.

```
Declare @myxml xml;
set @myxml = '<items count="2">
  <item id="561" quantity="1" />
  <item id="167" quantity="1" />
</items>'

select @myxml.query('//items');
Go
Declare @myxml xml;
set @myxml = '<ContactLog xmlns="http://adventure-works/contact">
  <Contact Date="2008-09-02T10:12:00" Type="Email">
    <Employee>adventure-works\linda3</Employee>
    <Notes>Customer confirmed delivery of order 71935.</Notes>
  </Contact>
  <Contact Date="2008-06-02T15:07:00" Type="Phone">
    <Employee>adventure-works\david8</Employee>
    <Employee>adventure-works\linda3</Employee>
    <Notes>Customer requested status update on order 71935. Informed customer it is being prepared for delivery.</Notes>
  </Contact>
</ContactLog>';

select @myxml.query('//ContactLog');
```

Comment: *default namespace* is the keywords..

Comment: har07  Sorry but did not get it, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should query in the proper namespace. Your second `SELECT` should read:

```
select @myxml.query('declare namespace pd="http://adventure-works/contact"; //pd:ContactLog') ;
```

An alternative way of writing this is the following:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://adventure-works/contact' AS pd)
SELECT  @myxml.query('//pd:ContactLog');
```

You can read more about how handling XML namespaces in SQL Server [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx)